# How would I go about randomly generating strings with certain parameters?

Tags: python, string

I want to create a program to randomly generate a string with this layout including dashes:

```
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Now the limitations are to only include:

Using random Letters: a to f
Using random Numbers: 0 to 9
User input for how many times to print a random generated code on a new line.

I'm fairly new to programming and I would like some advice on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Please post what you've tried (actual code is preferable to just verbal descriptions) and explain where you ran into problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are generating uuid. use [uuid](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html):

```
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('b80d8ad2-c0a5-4689-b39a-2c9869e906af')
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('35895e08-8d72-4bda-9e6c-2a3dd4c2197c')
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('fc3fb627-77e6-4598-9bf8-ac699b16d07a')
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('f6b3fe86-429a-4acd-a509-aa687705bfca')
```

Comment: How would I just get the code from within the UUID(' ') and assign that to a variable?

Comment: Don't worry, got it!
a = uuid.uuid4()  
str(a)

Comment: @lorde, `str(uuid.uuid4())`